# how do you take checkbox input using php that is controlled by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

hi i have a basic a check box list in my html which is controlled by a script that limits the checks to 4 boxes only . now i need to take only the checked boxes that the user has chosen , i cant seem to get a good idea to take it

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table>



<tr><td > </td></tr>
<tr><td ><input  type=checkbox  name="ckb" value="web" onclick='chkcontrol(0)';></td><td >Web Programming</tr>
<tr><td ><input type=checkbox name="ckb" value="data" onclick='chkcontrol(1)';></td><td >Data Structures</td></tr>
<tr><td ><input type=checkbox name="ckb" value="automata" onclick='chkcontrol(2)';></td><td >Automata</td></tr>
<tr><td ><input type=checkbox name="ckb" value="network" onclick='chkcontrol(3)';></td><td >Computer Networks</td></tr>
<tr><td ><input type=checkbox name="ckb" value="oraganization" onclick='chkcontrol(4)';></td><td >Computer Organization</td></td></tr>
<tr><td ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save&nbsp;</button></td></td></tr>


</table></form>
```

this is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function chkcontrol(j) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++) {
        if (document.form1.ckb[i].checked) {
            total = total + 1;
        }
        if (total > 4) {
            alert("Please Select only four")
            document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

now i tried changing the name of the checkbox to an array but then my JavaScript would not work . i need something that can work with both of them

Comment: Where is the script?

Comment: sorry , had some problems on my side , the script should be visible now

Comment: You will have to change the name, because this way you simply don't have a valid HTML structure. The last checkbox will always overwrite all the previous ones. As for your script, just add a class to your checkboxes and handle them through that, instead of accessing `document.form1.checkbox_name`.

Comment: Go back to using an array, but add the values of your checkboxes into the array. When the array gets to a length of 4, then you stop accepting values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need a different way of getting those checkboxes. Here's one way using [Element.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

```js
function chkcontrol(j) {
  var total = 0;
  
  const checkboxes = document.form1.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      total = total + 1;
    }
    if (total > 4) {
      alert("Please Select only four")
      checkboxes[j].checked = false;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="web" onclick='chkcontrol(0)' /></td><td>Web Programming</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="data" onclick='chkcontrol(1)' /></td><td>Data Structures</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="automata" onclick='chkcontrol(2)' /></td><td>Automata</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="network" onclick='chkcontrol(3)' /></td><td>Computer Networks</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="oraganization" onclick='chkcontrol(4)' /></td><td>Computer Organization</td></tr>
    <tr><td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save&nbsp;</button></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Changing `'input[type="checkbox"]'` to `'input[name="ckb[]"]'` would also work. Adding a class on the checkbox elements and selecting using those as mentioned by @El_Vanja should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `onclick` event, added class and listened to the event. The checkbox values are pushed into the array `checkedValues`.

```js
let checkedNo = 0;
let checkedValues = []
const el = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');


for (let i = 0; i < el.length; ++i) {
    el[i].addEventListener("change", () => {
            if (event.target.checked && (checkedNo === 4)) {
                event.target.checked = false;
                return;
            }
            if (!event.target.checked && (checkedNo > 0)) {
                checkedNo = checkedNo - 1;
                checkedValues = checkedValues.filter(e => e !== event.target.value);
            }
            if (event.target.checked) {
                checkedValues.push(event.target.value)
                checkedNo++
            }

            if (checkedNo === 4) {
                console.log(checkedValues)
            }

        }

    )
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table>
<tr><td > </td></tr>
<tr><td ><input class="checkbox"  type=checkbox  name="ckb" value="web" ></td><td >Web Programming</tr>
<tr><td ><input class="checkbox" type=checkbox name="ckb" value="data" ></td><td >Data Structures</td></tr>
<tr><td ><input class="checkbox" type=checkbox name="ckb" value="automata" ></td><td >Automata</td></tr>
<tr><td ><input class="checkbox" type=checkbox name="ckb" value="network" ></td><td >Computer Networks</td></tr>
<tr><td ><input class="checkbox" type=checkbox name="ckb" value="oraganization" ></td><td >Computer Organization</td></td></tr>
<tr><td ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save&nbsp;</button></td></td></tr>


</table></form>
```